# Categories, tags and thumbnails panels are not visible in the Block editor's post menu

Tags: block-editor, bug

Using the Block editor I'm not able to see or activate the Categories, tags and thumbnails panels.
I'm using a custom theme and all plugins are disables.

This is what it looks like in the block editor:

[image: block editor]

And when I go to Preferences -> panels there is no even option to activate those panels
[image: Preferences -> panels]

However when I use the TinyMCE editor with the [Classic Editor Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/) it appears:

[image]

Is this a bug?

### Errors shown in the console: (In the block editor)

> Failed to load resource:
> http://site.local/wp-json/wp/v2/block-patterns/categories?_locale=user
> the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden).
>
> Failed to load resource:
> http://site.local/wp-json/wp/v2/themes?context=edit&status=active&_locale=user
> the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden).
>
> Failed to load resource:
> http://site.local/wp-json/wp/v2/block-patterns/patterns?_locale=user
> the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden).

**Logs in an infinite loop**

**Error messages:**

```
{"code":"rest_cannot_view_active_theme","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to view the active theme.","data":{"status":401}}

{"code":"rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to view the registered block patterns.","data":{"status":401}}

{"code":"rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to view the registered block pattern categories.","data":{"status":401}}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: the 403 forbidden responses are why they don't show, you need to identify the cause of that, perhaps by trying to visit those REST API URLs yourself to see what the 403 forbidden response looks like. Have you been interfering with the roles and capabilities on your site? Or adding security plugins?

Comment: @TomJNowell I have added some security plugins in the past, but I uninstalled them and cleaned the DB. But That's still very odd that it appears in classic editor but not in the block editor

Comment: the HTTP 403 response prevents the block editor from using those features, as long as those REST API responses return a 403 forbidden the block editor can never show featured image etc. Their presence in the classic editor is completely irrelevant. You need to investigate why your REST API endpoints have started rejecting requests. The block editor has always worked this way

Answer (score 1):

Login out and in to Wordpress solved the problem